# Python - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

```
titles = [line.rstrip() for line in open('./nlp_class/all_book_titles.txt')]

# copy tokenizer from sentiment example
stopwords = set(w.rstrip() for w in open('./nlp_class/stopwords.txt'))
```

I tried to run the python file 'books.py' but it gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "books.py", line 14, in <module>
    titles = [line.rstrip() for line in open('./nlp_class/all_book_titles.txt')]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './nlp_class/all_book_titles.txt'
```

The full directory is: **C:\Python36\python_bible\nlp_class**
The 'books.py' file location: **C:\Python36\python_bible\books.py**
The full code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/4rd2knbu/

Comment: Does the file `C:\Python36\python_bible\nlp_class\all_book_titles.txt` exist?

Comment: yes both files exist

Comment: Have you tried giving the absolute, rather than relative, path: C:/Python36/python_bible/nlp_class/all_book_titles.txt

Comment: JsFiddle doesn't run Python code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you're using the UNIX path separator `/` on a Windows system instead of using the Windows path separator `\`. You can write OS-independent code using `os.path.join` (which will automatically use the correct separator):

```
import os

titles_file = os.path.join("nlp_class", "all_book_titles.txt")
titles = [line.rstrip() for line in open(titles_file)]

# copy tokenizer from sentiment example
stopwords_file = os.path.join("nlp_class", "stopwords.txt")
stopwords = set(w.rstrip() for w in open(stopwords_file))
```